# Is it illegal to provide samples from previous published work?

Tags: freelance, ghostwriter

I am a ghostwriter and I am currently looking for a new job. I have come across an article writing career. I am currently in the process of filling out an application and one of the questions asks me which niche of writing I specialize in. Then I need to provide two samples of my work per niche I specialize in.

This would be great, except all I have is non-fiction books that I have written for other people because I have only ever been a ghostwriter. My question is this: Would it be illegal for me to go into the non-fiction books I have written and pulled out a couple of paragraphs and make it look nice into a file for my sample work to apply for this job? Or, would it be illegal due to the plagiarism?

Correct me if I am wrong, but I feel like it wouldn't be a problem considering 1, I am not giving my employer the full book. 2, I am not providing any resources of where I go the previous information. And 3, I am not providing who published the book under my writing of the ghostwriter.

Really need answers, anything will help me in this issue of mine.

Comment: Might be better on https://law.stackexchange.com

Comment: I can't see any problem with quoting extracts from a published source. However, to demonstrate what *you* contributed, you'd need to quote the original author's private unpublished material and show what you changed. What does your ghostwriting contract say about confidentiality of the original draft?